# SQL Server: Select duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table:

| personId | Date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 15-09-2022 | London |
| abc123 | 15-09-2022 | Nottingham |
| efg321 | 12-09-2022 | Leeds |
| abc123 | 13-09-2022 | Birmingham |

I want to select and return the duplicate rows based on `Date` and `location` columns, for example, in the above table: personId 'abc123' is present at location both 'London' and 'Nottingham' on the same date, so I would like to return these rows.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT personId, Date FROM sampleTable GROUP BY personId, Date HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But it gives me the count. I want the rows with all three columns. Expected result:

| personId | Date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 15-09-2022 | London |
| abc123 | 15-09-2022 | Nottingham |

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Using the term duplicate is somewhat misleading, since you are specifying a **different** location.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh edited the question with expected result.

Comment: Did you consider getting it in one line? 
select personId, date, string_agg(location,',') from sample group by personId,date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    sampleTable.*
FROM
    sampleTable
    INNER JOIN -- acts as a filter here
        (
        SELECT
            personId,
            Date
        FROM
            sampleTable
        GROUP BY
            personId,
            Date
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
        ) problemTable
         ON sampleTable.personId = problemTable.personId
        AND sampleTable.Date = problemTable.Date
ORDER BY
    sampleTable.personId,
    sampleTable.Date,
    sampleTable.location
;
```

The derived `problemTable` calculates `personId/Date` combos that have multiple `sampleTable` rows. INNER JOINing `sampleTable` with `problemTable`, by nature of an INNER JOIN, returns an abridged version of `sampleTable`: one that *only* contains combos found within `problemTable` as well—and those are the ones you care about!

Using INNER JOIN as a filter mechanism is a common theme in SQL, so keep it in the back of your mind.

Comment: This could be a better answer if you explain the SQL by identifying why you have a derived table; what it does and then why you (INNER) join it back to the original sample table.  I believe it to be a valid answer; but helping someone understand why is just as important as a correct answer.  Pure SQL answers help; but more can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy using window functions.

Inner SQL returns same table with extra col that marks duplicate rows. Then outer sql filters rows that has duplicate

inner sql result

```
personid     date             location          check   
abc123       13-09-2022       Birmingham        1
abc123       15-09-2022       London            2
abc123       15-09-2022       Nottingham        2
efg321       12-09-2022       Leeds             1
```

final

```
personid     date             location          check   
abc123       15-09-2022       London            2
abc123       15-09-2022       Nottingham        2
```

SQL

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT
      personid,
      datecol,
      location,
      COUNT( personid ) OVER (PARTITION BY personid, datecol) AS check
     FROM sampletable
)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE check > 1
```